# Serving selected folders only

Tags: go, static

I have a Go static content website issue.
My structure looks like this:

```
|-Go
|--static/*
|--go.mod
|--main.go
```

When I serve the static content this way

```
    router.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")).ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
```

I can see the contents of go.mod in the url https://example.com/go.mod

Then I changed the code to

```
    router.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/*")).ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
```

I also tried

```
    router.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")).ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
```

I can no longer see the contents of go.mod in the url https://example.com/go.mod

But my logo is not visible anymore `<img src="/static/imgs/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>`

How can I only serve the contents of the `./static/` dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To server content under static dir:

```
http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
```

The requests for /imgs/logo.png then will be server from ./static/imgs/logo.png, (not /static/img/logo.png)

If you want to also include /static/ in your URLs:

```
http.StripPrefix("/static/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))
```

Comment: I tried "./static/" and the logo is still broken

Comment: With the first option, the logo URL is /imgs/logo.png, without the "/static"